# Laravel 5.2 y Entrust

Tags: php, laravel-5, permisos, users-roles

tengo un problema que no he podido resolver y ya llevo varias horas en el. Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.2 y el componente para administrar Roles y Permisos **Entrust**. Todo quedo bien configurado incluyendo los middleware que provee **Entrust**

```
'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
```

Ahora bien, estoy intentando configurar mis rutas y lo hago de esta manera:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
     //MIS RUTAS
});
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, cuando entro con admin tengo acceso a todo y cuando entro con el ROLE Basico estoy limitado, hasta ahi sigue todo bien, pero hay un perfil "ESPECIAL" que tiene acceso a todo, menos a una ruta, entonces hago lo siguiente:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|especial']], function() {
     //MIS RUTAS
});
```

Al hacer esto, cuando entro con un usuario de role "admin" todo funciona correcto, pero cuando entro con un usuario de role "especial" no lo detecta, es decir me devuelve el mensaje de error que configure de que tiene el acceso prohibido al link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 3 opciones:

Puedes crear grupos de permisos dentro del mismo grupo

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|especial']], function() {
    // RUTAS PARA LOS 2 PERMISOS
    Route::get('/', 'FooController@index');
    Route::get('/bar', 'BarController@index');

    // RUTAS SOLO PARA ADMIN
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
        Route::get('/admin', 'FooController@index');
    });
    // RUTAS SOLO PARA ESPECIAL
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:especial']], function() {
        Route::get('/especial', 'FooController@index');
    });
});
```

Filtro para una sola ruta a través del middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|especial']], function() {
    // RUTAS PARA LOS 2 PERMISOS
    Route::get('/', 'FooController@index');
    Route::get('/bar', 'BarController@index');

    // FILTRO PARA LA RUTA SOLO ACCESIBLE POR ADMIN
    Route::get('/admin', ['middleware' => ['role:admin'], 'uses' => 'FooController@index']);

});
```

Filtro a través del Entrust

```
// Redirecciona a /home si no es admin
Entrust::routeNeedsRole('admin*', 'admin', Redirect::to('/home'));

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|especial']], function() {
    // RUTAS PARA LOS 2 PERMISOS
    Route::get('/', 'FooController@index');
    Route::get('/bar', 'BarController@index');
});
```